# youtube playback api - some clips won't play

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api

so, i'm programming whit the new playback api from youtube and i noticed that some clips say: "this video can not be played on moblie devices". now my question is why?
and is there some way to get a round this problem. like the `webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("user-agent-string");` function.

is there some way to do that in the api, or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

have you read this?

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html

There are reasons playback restrictions are put into place. Please make sure that you've read the YouTube API Terms of Service and do not circumvent playback restrictions. The terms of service can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms